# Feathering the edges of a Volumetric shape object

Tags: texturing, volumetrics

Hi Blendonians (just came up with that haha)

I apologise in advance for having no screenshots, but I think I can explain the problem.

I have a street scene. On the road, there's a sewage grate. I'd like to have some "steam" coming from the grate but I really can't use the smoke simulator... I've tried and it's way too slow for some reason, even though I've got a beast of a machine. Maybe I'll attempt it again in the future, but this technique I'm trying should work, I just can't figure out one part.

So I created a cube, made it into a sort of cone shape, added a volume scatter shader controlled by a noise texture to the volume material output.

This gave me the exact look for the steam I wanted. It looks really nice, especially when light hits it. But the steam is cut off harshly at the edges of the cube.

So I added a gradient texture and tried literally hundreds of different settings and combinations. I got really close, but the cut at the edge of the cube is still there. I've been through loads of tutorial videos about making clouds with volume objects, how to use gradients etc, but nothing is working.

What I need is a way of feathering the volume so it's invisible at the edges of the object.

If no one can explain it to me from that info, I'll get some screen shots soon and upload the blend file.

Many thanks in advance.

Screenshots added.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: so why did gradient failed?

Comment: It didn't fail, it just didn't remove the edge completely.